# can someone check if the following conceptual function is `non-blocking`

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

Pleas check if this the following sample function is `non-blocking`

```
sample_function = function(input, fn){
  let count=0;
  for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM DB WHERE id=?`,[input[i].id], function(error, result){
      process_function(input[i], function(error, result2){
        count++;
        if(count===input.length){
          fn(input)
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

If the whole `for loop` would take about 10 seconds to complete.(5seconds to read from the database and 5seconds to process using the local thread(`process_function`), would the `for loop` block other new events for 10 seconds? If so, how would you fix this function to be non-blocking. I am trying to learn. Please help

Comment: The whole `for` loop will take only a couple ms to complete, because you're not using `await` (and even if you were using `await`, it wouldn't block anything else - it's not like `alert`)

Comment: what if the `input.length` were couple thousands and each `process_function` invoke takes like half a second(assume its CPU intensive)

Comment: No matter how long `process_function` takes, the `for` loop will terminate almost immediately, because the `db.query` callback is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loop is synchronized but inside the for loop db.query is not synchronized.
So in for loop, each query will fire one by one sequence but their output will not appear in sequence.

But you can solve this issue with async and await. It can make your code inside for loop synchronized.

```
sample_function = async function(input, fn){
    let count=0;
    for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        const query_data = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM DB WHERE id=?, 
                           [input[i].id]);
        const process_data = await process_function(input[i]);
        count++;
        if(count===input.length){
            fn(input)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fn(input)` isn't needed as well. It likely should be replaced with `async` returned  value.